# installing jQuery slider - add text instead of pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have succesfully created a slider on my website by the help of jquery files from www.bxslider.com

On bx slider is clearly written that:

> Slides can contain images, video, or HTML content

right now on this code, i have images from bxslider website. but when i add some text to it, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<div class="outside">
  <h3>This div is outside of the slider</h3>
  <p><span id="slider-prev"></span> | <span id="slider-next"></span></p>
</div>


<script>
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: 'Onward →',
  prevText: '← Go back'
});
</script>
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/nwvW9/

Can someone help me add text to it instead of images?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/nwvW9/2/ what's wrong? seems to work just fine

Comment: try now, http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/nwvW9/6/

it does not work now for some reason

Comment: I fiddled with this as well. It seems like the slider doesn't properly load if text is in the first position.

Comment: why is that?is there a way to get rid of that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a small fix to your code and it is working.
you have to add a transparent image(so size become less) and make it hidden by adding a class or by directly adding style tag. This works because the plugin you are using, always find 'img' tag to display image.

here is the code which I edited for first 'li'.

```
 <li>
  <img src="http://bxslider.com//images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" style="display:none" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc nec magna ut orci porttitor ..... </p>
 </li>
```

here is the updated jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/nwvW9/11/